# when do you need to use Mono instead of Flux?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

Mono is defined as a Reactive Streams Publisher with basic rx operators that completes successfully by emitting an element,and the Flux is the same form 0 to N elements.
When and why use Mono instead of Flux for only one element stream?

Answer (score 2):

Mono is designed to return one element when one element is emitted then Mono knows that it completed its purpose. Flux is used when we want to subscribe to more elements for example when we are expecting the collection to be returned.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases Flux might replace Mono, but it is better to use Mono since it offers only operators that are relevant in context of zero or one item

For example Mono is being used in more specific scenarios like an HTTP request 
(one request -> one response).

Answer (score 0):

Much of the time, you are doing some calculation or calling an administration and you anticipate precisely one outcome (or perhaps zero or one outcome), and not a gathering that contains potentially different outcomes. In such cases, it's progressively helpful to have a `Mono`.

Contrast it with "customary" Java: you would not utilize `List` as the arrival sort of any technique that can return zero or one outcome. You would utilize `Optional` rather, which makes it promptly evident that you don't anticipate more than one outcome.